# Which is a good opensource user management system?

Tags: php

I'm new to php/mySQL and am trying to create a website which will allow users to register. In future, there will be a paid content area where content will be shown based on the payment status.

Is there a good opensource lightweight framework which takes care of the user management part? (Register, edit user info, retrieve lost password etc). I'm a flash platform developer and not aware of how to take care of stuff like session hijacking, XSS etc.

Should I go ahead and learn to do all this on my own, without using any framework? I thought of using Wordpress' user management system, but not sure how easy that would be. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [Drupal](http://www.drupal.com)

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not used it, [CakePHP offers user management and access control list functionality](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/user-permissions-and-cakephp-acl), backed by other helpers that take care of sanitizing input. I'm not sure if an MVC framework is ideal for your needs, though, as it would steepen your learning curve.

I'm sure other answers will recommend 'pluggable' user authentication and ACL classes, which will accrue votes based on how useful other people found them.

I rolled my own a long time ago and tend to use it in lighter MVC frameworks like Code Igniter, or in the absence of any framework at all. As you use ready made classes, you'll naturally and quickly begin developing your own to better suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are there any ready made classes you'd recommend for this purpose?

Comment: @Lost_in_code: A simple search yields hundreds (possibly thousands) of them, some are 5+ years old. I'm sure other answers to this question will make recommendations. The link I gave is the only one that I'm (reasonably) sure is solid.