# PHP user access management script?

Tags: php, accessibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is a good opensource user management system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445566/which-is-a-good-opensource-user-management-system)

I'm looking for a PHP script or software that would help manage user system access.  For a set of users which I could read from a config file, I could then see for each user, which systems they have access to.  Conversely, for each system or server from a list of servers also read from a config file, I could see which users have access to this server.

I would then like to be able to add or remove users access to those systems by for instance running a script on those servers or systems.

Is there anything like this already existing?

Comment: a config file as iiiin a database?

Comment: no, config file as in text file or xml file

Comment: Well, that is incredibly insecure. Are you 100% sure you just want it in a xml file on the server?

Comment: Are you trying to manage system users via a web interface? Something like http://webmin.com/

Comment: everything is internal.  why wouldn't we want it in an xml file on the server?

Comment: webmin.com is neat.  We are trying to manage sytem users via a web interface.  But webmin has really a lot more features than we need.  We are just looking at user access.  Not all users on every server, but just a limited group of users we define in a config file. Our own limited set of users.  And not all the systems are unix based.  Some are windows.

Answer (score 0):

Most php frameworks offer user authentication services. Take a look at some of those, or at [drupal](http://www.drupal.com/).

Comment: I'm not really looking for user authentication.  I am in an environment where there is different user authentication required to access the various systems.  Different user ids and different or possibly the same passwords.  I was looking for a way that I could keep track of the users and which systems they have access to, as well as adding and deleting users from those systems when needed.

Comment: I don't really need a full-blown cms like drupal.